# Kendo uistock chart is not visuable in IE9 and Mozilla?

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

we have a page which has stock charts in it, and recently we noticed that the  stockchart are 
not displayed in IE8 & mozilla .

Aside from the Stock chart, in the same page we have also grids which are working fine. Is there any such known bug with the Stockcharts in IE8 & mozilla, and if yes is there some kind of  workaround for this problem.

Comment: Your IE security policy might be preventing the chart from rendering. Please check this help topic - http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/dataviz/troubleshooting

Comment: What is the version of Firefox that you're using?

Comment: Firefox version 17.0.1 is i am using

Comment: docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/dataviz/troubleshooting I had already tried this in my system by default it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

there here [a patch to simulate canvas](https://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) on ie, and mozilla check css or html tags well